Does google ask developers to offload products to their own server and not fetch them using the play library?
Does Google recommend offloading product (subscriptions) data to a developer's own server and fetching the details from there, instead of directly querying the Google Play Console, to optimize load management? If yes, how can one create a ProductDetails object, given that the class does not provide a public constructor?
I tried creating an instance of the ProductDetails class but there is no constructor

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
